# Rabbitmq synchronization non empty slave

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, high-availability

In rabbitmq, if I have a queue mirrored across two nodes and the sync-mode is not automatic and if due to some reason partition occurs, and both the mirrors grow independently. What happens when I restart the non trusted partition? Will the data in the non trusted partition get lost after restart? Or will new data  be appended to the queues and in due course of time data in both queues will converge?